# Show month name in Subtitle in FSCalender in swift

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

i'm working with the FSCalender in swift. I'm trying to show the calender in a week format and want ot just show days name and dates under it. and under the dates in the subttile i want to show the month name. I have used the delegates for the subtitle but it isn't showing the subttitle. This is my code for the calender,`calender.scope = .week
        calender.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        calender.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9957205653, green: 0.9922057986, blue: 0.9962993264, alpha: 1)
        calender.today = nil
        calender.appearance.headerDateFormat = nil`

```
 func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar!, subtitleFor date: NSDate!) -> String! {
    return "March"
}
```

I have written static march in subtitle but i want the actual month name under it. How can i show that? I want my calender to look like this,
[image]

Comment: add LunarFormatter to get months and use func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, subtitleFor date: Date) -> String? {
        guard self.lunar else {
            return nil
        }
        return self.lunarFormatter.string(from: date)
    }

Comment: How can we add Lunar Formatter? @Vinodh

Comment: refer the same project of FSCalendar Lunar Formatter class available in that change the calendar to georgian can change month names in that

Comment: i didn't get it , if u plz explain in detail or in answer? @Vinodh